# Search results show only content by admin post authors

Tags: search, user-roles

In my current wordpress project there is an issue with search results. The project includes users of a custom role `competitor` who are able to upload images in the media library.

Since thoseattachments are not included by default in Wordpress search results, I added them like this in `functions.php`:

```
function fw_attachment_search( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_search ) {
       $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'attachment' ) );
       $query->set( 'post_status', array( 'publish', 'inherit' ) );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'fw_attachment_search' );
```

Now when searching for terms included in attachment titles, attachments are listed within the search results, but only those whose post author's role is `administrator`. Attachments uploaded by users with custom role `competitor` are not listed.

Why is that happening? How can I also find attachments that are uploaded by competitors?

I even tried the plugin [relevanssi](https://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/) but that did not return any other results than the regular search engine.

Any help?

Comment: I don't usually deal with post attachments, but have you checked that attachments uploaded by competitors have the publish status =  inherit? I know it does by default, but you could go to the database and make sure that the criteria you have returns any posts.

Comment: Yes, all attachments have `post_status = inherit`, whether their `post_author` is `administrator` or `competitor`.